# Make text on a button full the screen and detect the button press

Tags: screen, imagebutton

I have found some code by Scott Lund on Catch the CowsCode Bits and Bits of Thoughts on Coding for Android. see:  http://catchthecows.com/?p=72 this code creates a button and enlarges text to fill the full button size.

I am trying without luck to detect a button press on the new button class BigTextButton

```
package com.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class BigTextButton extends ImageButton {
    String mText = "";
    Paint mTextPaint;

    int mViewWidth;
    int mViewHeight;
    int mTextBaseline;

    public BigTextButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public BigTextButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        parseAttrs(attrs);
        init();
    }

    public BigTextButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        parseAttrs(attrs);
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Dig out Attributes to find text setting
     * 
     * This could be expanded to pull out settings for textColor, etc if desired
     * 
     * @param attrs
     */

    private void parseAttrs(AttributeSet attrs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
            String s = attrs.getAttributeName(i);
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
                mText = attrs.getAttributeValue(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence text) {
        mText = text.toString();
        onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    /**
     * initialize Paint for text, it will be modified when the view size is set
     */
    private void init() {
        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    /**
     * set the scale of the text Paint objects so that the text will draw and
     * take up the full screen width
     */
    void adjustTextScale() {
        // do calculation with scale of 1.0 (no scale)
        mTextPaint.setTextScaleX(1.0f);
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        // ask the paint for the bounding rect if it were to draw this
        // text.
        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), bounds);

        // determine the width
        int w = bounds.right - bounds.left;

        // calculate the baseline to use so that the
        // entire text is visible including the descenders
        int text_h = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
        mTextBaseline = bounds.bottom + ((mViewHeight - text_h) / 2);

        // determine how much to scale the width to fit the view
        float xscale = ((float) (mViewWidth - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()))
                / w;

        // set the scale for the text paint
        mTextPaint.setTextScaleX(xscale);
    }

    /**
     * determine the proper text size to use to fill the full height
     */
    void adjustTextSize() {
        if (mText.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(100);
        mTextPaint.setTextScaleX(1.0f);
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        // ask the paint for the bounding rect if it were to draw this
        // text
        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), bounds);

        // get the height that would have been produced
        int h = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

        // make the text text up 70% of the height
        float target = (float) mViewHeight * .7f;

        // figure out what textSize setting would create that height
        // of text
        float size = ((target / h) * 100f);

        // and set it into the paint
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(size);
    }

    /**
     * When the view size is changed, recalculate the paint settings to have the
     * text on the fill the view area
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // save view size
        mViewWidth = w;
        mViewHeight = h;

        // first determine font point size
        adjustTextSize();
        // then determine width scaling
        // this is done in two steps in case the
        // point size change affects the width boundary
        adjustTextScale();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // let the ImageButton paint background as normal
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // draw the text
        // position is centered on width
        // and the baseline is calculated to be positioned from the
        // view bottom
        canvas.drawText(mText, mViewWidth / 2, mViewHeight - mTextBaseline,
                mTextPaint);

    }
}
```

Comment: I worked it out.         BigTextButton progress = (BigTextButton) findViewById(R.id.progress);        
         progress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {                
    
              // Do something when clicked
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out myself, the following code detects a press and opens the editing screen2.xml

```
 // open the editor screen2.xml if you click the bigTextButton1 eg line 1 of screen
    BigTextButton progress = (BigTextButton) findViewById(R.id.bigTextButton1);        
    progress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {                

            // Do something when clicked
            // Starting a new Intent to switch screens
            Intent Config = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Configuration.class);

            // starting new activity
            startActivity(Config);
        }
    });
```